# javascript cannot convert undefined or null to object question

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I am trying javascript for the first time and I am having this trouble with the example:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/web-scraping-and-parsing-html-with-node-js-and-cheerio

It is a web scrapper example that uses got and cheerio, both of which I have installed. But when i run the sample code it gives me 'cannot convert undefined or null to object error.

Why is that? I didn't change anything from the example at all.

the code in question:

```
  const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

  $('a').each((i, link) => {
    const href = link.attribs.href;
    console.log(href);
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: I think you receive null or undefine in response.body.

Comment: This needs a complete, runnable [mcve] showing how `response.body` was defined. There is more code in the link, and if I run it all, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

How does your index.js file look like? I did the tutorial and my code is working. Maybe you are miss typed the url?

Here is my index.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const got = require("got");

const vgmUrl = "https://www.vgmusic.com/music/console/nintendo/nes";

got(vgmUrl)
  .then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
    $("a").each((i, link) => {
      const href = link.attribs.href;
      console.log(href);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: mine looks pretty similar, excpet your require has double quotes and mine uses single quotes but that doesn't seem like it should be related right?

Comment: ok so when i copy paste your code into my vscode and run it i get the exact same error so it must be something else. how do you run it? node index.js?

Comment: I Have a plugin to change single quotes to double quotes, that wont be your problem. And I run it with 'node index.js'

Comment: Did the your step work before adding the "a" tag? the "Using Got to retrieve data to use with Cheerio" step?